# AC Current confusion

Tags: current, ac, generator, electrical

when an AC generator generates current it alternates, so does both terminals of ac generators has current means both are live wires ?

Comment: Half of period one terminal is "live" and other half of period the other terminal is "live". For example: 1Hz has a period (360 degrees of conduction) of 1s, which means that positive half of sine wave "shows up" at the first terminal (or L), and the other half of sine wave, which is negative wave, shows up on the second terminal (or N) of the sine wave generator.

Comment: an AC generator is grounded at one terminal and another terminal is we call hot,live... does that mean 50% current is going waste because every half of time 1 terminal is neutral and other is hot vice versa. So when the grounded terminal become hot wire all the current goes down to earth ??

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.  Be sure to take the tour to get the most out of this site:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: Look at G36s answer

Answer (score 2):

Having a current flow does not make a terminal "live". Having the ability to deliver a stinging electric shock might be more a recommendation for calling a terminal "live". This means you have to distinguish between voltage and current.

Clearly, on a simple single phase AC generator, current flow is the same on both wires and if you touched one of those wires you might not feel anything until one of those wires became grounded (as per normal electricial regulations). Then you could call the ungrounded terminal "live" and the grounded terminal "neutral".

Comment: So you're saying that an AC generator is designed this way so one wire has potential (Voltage) but charge flow on both of them.

Comment: "Potential" or voltage (or sometimes called pressure) is developed across both wires in order to move charge (create current).

Answer (score 0):

No, wrong. Current always flows in closed loop circuit. Hence what comes out from the neutral wire must comes in (return) into hot wire. This is First Kirchhoff's Law. No current will flow into the earth.

[image]

Comment: But you could equally well draw the GND on the upper conductor, so there's no real distinction between the two terminals.